# Xcode Missing Symbols on UnityFramework?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm triying to build an unity app for iOS but for some reason when i try archive it or build it it breaks down at the start. I really don't know the cause

I tried cleaning it, again and again. Nothing seems to work. It managed to build when I deleted UnityFramework but that clearly is not a solution. I've looked around for answers but most of them are for firebase or another external library, and don't seem to alling with the errors I'm having.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular", referenced from:

```
  ModuleManager::Load() in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_Modules_0_4ia5l.o)
```

"RegisterAllClasses()", referenced from:

```
  InitializeEngineNoGraphics() in libiPhone-lib.a(Runtime_Misc_0_4ia5l.o)
```

"RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls()", referenced from:

```
  RegisterAllInternalCalls() in libiPhone-lib.a(MonoICallRegistration_81zo5.o)
```

"_g_CodegenRegistration", referenced from:

```
  il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Init(char const*) in libil2cpp.a(External_il2cpp_builds_libil2cpp_vm_5_ecvbo.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9bb5.png)